# Django Model.ObjectDoesNotExist Exceptions

Tags: python, django, exception

Here I want to get the winner matching the query. If I dont have that winner I want to go for winner creation

```
winner_check = Winner.objects.get(win_date__year=today.year, win_date__month=today.month, win_date__day=today.day)
if winner_check:
    final_winner = winner_check
    message = "Winner already generated for today."
    return anything

else:
    winner_index = random.randint(0, len(player_list)-1)
    winner = player_list[winner_index]
    return anything
```

Is this the right way for doing or I should generate exceptions

```
try:
    winner_check = Winner.objects.get(win_date__year=today.year, win_date__month=today.month, win_date__day=today.day)
    final_winner = winner_check
    message = "Winner already generated for today"
    return anything
except Winner.DoesNotExist:
    winner_index = random.randint(0, len(player_list)-1)
    final_winner = player_list[winner_index]
    return anything
```

Also what if I just want to get the not create

```
try:
    winner_check = Winner.objects.get(win_date__year=today.year, win_date__month=today.month, win_date__day=today.day)
except Winner.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Here if there is no user I want to process further returning a message like "There is no winner"
Can anyone guide me through exceptions on get() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend you to define your `win_date` field as [`models.DateField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#datefield) in order to do look-ups using `datetime.date` object and avoid such use below;

```
winner = Winner.objects.get(win_date__year=today.year, win_date__month=today.month, win_date__day=today.day)
```

Instead you will be able to look for a winner like this;

```
from django.utils import timezone

winner = Winner.objects.get(win_date=timezone.now().date())
```

As for your problem, you can use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method for searching a winner with the given `win_date` and creating a new one if not found.

```
winner, created = Winner.objects.get_or_create(win_date=timezone.now().date(), defaults={"name": "Vishnu", "surname": "Raj"})

if created:
    print "New winner has been generated"
else:
    print "Winner has already been generated for today"
```

---

For the second part of your question, about retrieving objects and handling `DoesNotExist` exceptions, I'd suggest you use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) which raises `Http404` error when object was not found.

```
from django.utils import get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404

def get_winner(request, id):
    try:
        winner = get_object_or_404(Winner, pk=id)
    except Http404:
        winner = Winner(win_date=..., name=..., surname=...)
```

It is always almost a better approach to send user `404` error, rather than `500` for these kind of cases, because 500 means a server error whereas 404 means "not found".

Comment: got it... what if I didn't find the winner and want to set a winner

Comment: Can you expand the term "setting a winner"?

Comment: like if there is no winner with id=5 then I want to generate a user like I did in second block of code with try catch in my question. Is it right to do ?

Comment: Yes, it'd be the right place to do that. I've updated my answer to cover that case.